# Highchart : by passing FROM DATE and TO DATE x axis labels should set

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have two dropdown `from_date` and `to_date` .based on selected values from these two `dropdowns` i want to make x axis labels.
currently
i am using the following code .but it does not work. please tell me what is the issue.

```
xAxis: {
                type: "datetime",
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%m-%d'   
                },
                tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                min: Date.UTC(from_date),
                max: Date.UTC(to_date)
       },
```

**edit:**

now i am getting with following code [**see fiidle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/LLExL/3046/). i am hard coding the date if it is from variable it is not working [**see fiiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/LLExL/3045/).

```
 xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        min: Date.UTC(2003, 8, 25),
                        max: Date.UTC(2003, 9, 8),
                        range: Date.UTC(2003, 9, 8) - Date.UTC(2003, 8, 25),
                        ordinal: false,
                        endOnTick: false,
                        startOnTick: false
                    },
```

Comment: did you print Date.UTC(from_date) and Date.UTC(to_date), is it show  correct output?

Comment: no it not showing. idoono y

Comment: but i am able to alert to_date and from_date variable

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code

Comment: @RahulGupta fiidle created. question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here the working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/We7zb/)**.

The problem is that you are mistaken regarding the date initialization:

**This is incorrect**

```
var from_date='2014,30,06';
Date.UTC(from_date); //here variable value is passed as a single string with value : '2014,30,06'
```

**This is correct**

```
Date.UTC(2014,30,06);// This means that you are passing three different parameters "year", "month" and "day" for date initialization
```

**So to initialize the date from string we have split the string using `javascript split function` as shown below**

```
var from_date='2014,30,06';
var arr_from_date = from_date.split(","); 
//alert(arr_from_date[0]+" "+arr_from_date[1]+" "+arr_from_date[2]);
arr_from_date[0] //2014 has year value
arr_from_date[1] //30 has day value
arr_from_date[2] //06 has month value
```

So the final JS code is:

```
var from_date='2014,30,06';
var arr_from_date = from_date.split(","); 
//alert(arr_from_date[0]+" "+arr_from_date[2]+" "+arr_from_date[1]);
var to_date='2014,30,07';
var arr_to_date = to_date.split(","); 

var new_from_date = Date.UTC(arr_from_date[0], arr_from_date[2], arr_from_date[1]);

var new_to_date = Date.UTC(arr_to_date[0], arr_to_date[2], arr_to_date[1]);
$('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {

                        type: 'datetime',
                        min: new_from_date,
                        max: new_to_date,
                        range: new_to_date - new_from_date,
                        ordinal: false,
                        endOnTick: false,
                        startOnTick: false

    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});
```

Comment: Thanks.In X-Axis it shows ``04:00, 08:00, etc``. why it's showing like that? I need only dates like ``6 June 2014``.

Comment: Sorry ! I mistook the date format as 'yyyy-mm-dd'. I have updated my fiddle and code. Now you can check it. It is now working as expected !

Comment: thanks alot.. can u do change in ur fiddle to display year also

Comment: For datetime label formatting you can refer the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/ddELH/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how are you using `Date.UTC()`. `Date.UTC(year, month, day, .. )` is taking a couple of arguments, not one argument which is string, like this: `'2014,30,06'`.

See example how this should be done: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/3049/

```
var from_date = '2014,30,06'.split(',');
var to_date = '2014,30,07'.split(',');
var min = Date.UTC(from_date[0], from_date[2], from_date[1]);
var max = Date.UTC(to_date[0], to_date[2], to_date[1]);
$('#container').highcharts({

  xAxis: {

     type: 'datetime',
     min: min,
     max: max,
     range: max - min,
     ordinal: false,
     endOnTick: false,
     startOnTick: false

  },

  series: [{
     data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]

});
```

Note: Second argument (month) for `Date.UTC()` is starting from 0 (January), not from 1 (which is February).